# MongoError: The dotted field .. is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, meteor, schema

I am trying to update a document with a matching nested attribute with the following query

```
upsertByCommentThreadId: function(commentThread) {
    return CommentThreads.update({
         'youtube.commentThreadId': commentThread.youtube.commentThreadId 
      },
      {
        $set: commentThread
      },
      {
        upsert: true
      }
    );
  }
```

Schema:

```
Schema({
  youtube: {
    type: Object
  },
  'youtube.etag': {
    type: String
  },
  'youtube.commentThreadId': {
    type: String,
    index: 1
  },
  ...
```

But I get an error

```
Exception while invoking method ... MongoError: The dotted field 'youtube.commentThreadId' in 'youtube.commentThreadId' is not valid for storage.
```

Im not sure how else I can query nested attributes, if not through dot notation

Comment: Does your commentThread has the whole document, including the _id? $set replaces the value of a field with a particular value, if you want to replace the whole document check Replace a document section in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/

Comment: Did you find a way around this? Having the same problem. It seems Meteor 1.2 will have a [fix](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/e02bf0fb30ed67e4f45417986a548b04de802e1d) for it.

Comment: Or replace to **&#46;**

Answer (score 13):

It's the restrictions on field name before mongo 3.6 , now you can update mongo server to version 3.6 or higher to solve this problem.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions

Answer (score 7):

The error occurs because MongoDB cannot work when there are dots present in the key. A similar error,

```
MongoError: The dotted field '2016.11.14' in 'myData.days.2016.11.14' is
            not valid for storage.
```

occurs when the code is:

```
day = "2016.11.14"
myData.days[ day ] = 11
```

When the data is changed to

```
day = "2016_11_14"
```

The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to flatten your **`$set`** operator param:

```
schema.update( {
  'youtube.commentThreadId': commentThread.youtube.commentThreadId
},
{
  $set: {
    // Here is my change
    'youtube.commentThreadId': commentThread.youtube.commentThreadId
  }
},
{ /* opts */});
```

You're not showing your `commentThread` (input param for that `upsertByCommentThreadId()` function - but I suspect you are sending the object, judging by that query part. Example, you have:

```
let commentThread = {
  youtube: {
    commentThreadId: 12345
  }
};
```

So your query part is ok, but the `$set` expects a simple key:value, where key must be a string.

So, you are sending something like:

```
CommentThreads.update({

     // Here it's ok, as it's translated to:
     // { 'youtube.commentThreadId': 12345 }
     'youtube.commentThreadId': commentThread.youtube.commentThreadId 
  },
  {

    // but this gets expanded to a deeply nested object, like:
    // { $set: { youtube: {commentThreadId: 12345}}} 
    $set: commentThread
  },
  {/* opts */}
);
```

So, your **`$set`** operator wants a simple `{ key: value }`, where *`key`* is a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your schema should be if you want to query nested attributes :

```
Schema({
  youtube: {
    etag:String,
    commentThreadId : {
      type: String,
      index: 1
    }
  },
...
```

Then you can use `'youtube.commentThreadId':'something'` to query nested attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the similar issue and upgraded the mongo version from 3.2 to 4.2 and now it's seems working fine.

You can follow the below procedure for centos machine to upgrade the mongodb version:-

First of all, you need to create a repository **/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo**  file so that yum knows where to find latest MongoDB packages.

Please replace redhat/7 with the code name appropriate for your distribution and version as listed below:

Put the below content in that repo file which you have created:-

```
[mongodb-org-4.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/4.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc
```

Now you can simply issue the following command to install the latest version of MongoDB:
$ sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

Now you can verify the version by running command:-

```
mongo
```